# JavaScript scope issue with global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the number of views a video has had (video.numviews) so I can populate another script to make a graphic. My global variable video looks like this:

```
var video = 
$(function(){
    $('#usersnav ul li a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var htmlString  = '<ul id="videoslisting">';
        var channelname = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
        var ytapiurl    = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'+channelname+'/uploads?alt=json&max-results=10';

        $.getJSON(ytapiurl, function(data) {
            $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
                var title    = item['title']['$t'];
                var videoid  = item['id']['$t'];

                var pubdate  = item['published']['$t'];
                var fulldate = new Date(pubdate).toLocaleDateString();

                var thumbimg = item['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url'];
                var tinyimg1 = item['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][1]['url'];
                var tinyimg2 = item['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][2]['url'];
                var tinyimg3 = item['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][3]['url'];

                var vlink    = item['media$group']['media$content'][0]['url'];
                var ytlink   = item['media$group']['media$player'][0]['url'];
                var numviews = item['yt$statistics']['viewCount'];
                var numcomms = item['gd$comments']['gd$feedLink']['countHint'];

                htmlString +='<li class="clearfix"><h2>' + title + '</h2>';
                htmlString +='<div class="videothumb"><a href="' + ytlink + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + thumbimg + '" width="480" height="360"></a></div>';
                htmlString +='<div class="meta"><p>Published on <strong>' + fulldate + '</strong></p><p>Total views: <strong>' + commafy(numviews) + '</strong></p>' +
                    '<p>Total comments: <strong>'+ numcomms +'</strong></p>' +
                    '<p><a href="'+ ytlink +'" class="external" target="_blank">View on YouTube</a></p>' +
                    '<p><a href="'+ vlink +'" class="external" target="_blank">View in Fullscreen</a></p>';
                // hiding the alt thumbnails
                //+
                //'<p><strong>Alternate Thumbnails</strong>:<br><img src="'+ tinyimg1 +'"> ' +
                //'<img src="' + tinyimg2 + '"> <img src="'+ tinyimg3 +'"></p></div></li>';
            }); // end each loop

            $('#videos').html(htmlString + "</ul>");
});
```

I need then to use video.numviews in the code below which is stored in a different file from the code above:

```
    // code for chart display
var videoChart = video.numviews;

        //Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
         var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    //This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx);
    {

    for (var i=0; i<videoChart.length; i++);


        var data = [

            {
                value: i,
                color:"#F38630"
            },
            {
                value : i,
                color : "#E0E4CC"
            },
            {
                value : i,
                color : "#69D2E7"
            }
        ];
    }
    var options = {
        scaleFontColor: "#f00",
        datasetStrokeWidth: 20
    };

    new Chart(ctx).Pie(data,options);
```

There seem to be a scoping issue, any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the video variable global like you did but not assign it to the document.ready function. Instead you can

```
//var video = {}; //Will only "collect' the last value as its being reassigned every loop cycle. 
var video = []; //To get all the values through the $.each loop

$(function(){
    $('#usersnav ul li a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var htmlString  = '<ul id="videoslisting">';
        var channelname = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
        var ytapiurl    = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'+channelname+'/uploads?alt=json&max-results=10';

        $.getJSON(ytapiurl, function(data) {
            $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
                var title    = item['title']['$t'];
                var videoid  = item['id']['$t'];

                var pubdate  = item['published']['$t'];
                var fulldate = new Date(pubdate).toLocaleDateString();

                var thumbimg = item['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url'];
                var tinyimg1 = item['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][1]['url'];
                var tinyimg2 = item['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][2]['url'];
                var tinyimg3 = item['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][3]['url'];

                var vlink    = item['media$group']['media$content'][0]['url'];
                var ytlink   = item['media$group']['media$player'][0]['url'];
                var numviews = item['yt$statistics']['viewCount'];
                var numcomms = item['gd$comments']['gd$feedLink']['countHint'];

                htmlString +='<li class="clearfix"><h2>' + title + '</h2>';
                htmlString +='<div class="videothumb"><a href="' + ytlink + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + thumbimg + '" width="480" height="360"></a></div>';
                htmlString +='<div class="meta"><p>Published on <strong>' + fulldate + '</strong></p><p>Total views: <strong>' + commafy(numviews) + '</strong></p>' +
                    '<p>Total comments: <strong>'+ numcomms +'</strong></p>' +
                    '<p><a href="'+ ytlink +'" class="external" target="_blank">View on YouTube</a></p>' +
                    '<p><a href="'+ vlink +'" class="external" target="_blank">View in Fullscreen</a></p>';
                // hiding the alt thumbnails
                //+
                //'<p><strong>Alternate Thumbnails</strong>:<br><img src="'+ tinyimg1 +'"> ' +
                //'<img src="' + tinyimg2 + '"> <img src="'+ tinyimg3 +'"></p></div></li>';
                //video.numviews = numviews;
                video.push(numviews);

            }); // end each loop

            $('#videos').html(htmlString + "</ul>");

});
```

Keep in mind though that the numviews will take on the last value of the each loop that you are running. Its possible to set up the video object so that its an array and we push the values to is instead of this.

The code can be cleaned up alot more in my opinion but that should solve your scoping issues...

Second Part:

```
// code for chart display
var videoChart = video; //Not necessary to reassign the value. 

    //Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
     var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
//This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx);
{

for (var i=0; i<videoChart.length; i++);


    var data = [

        {
            value: i,
            color:"#F38630"
        },
        {
            value : i,
            color : "#E0E4CC"
        },
        {
            value : i,
            color : "#69D2E7"
        }
    ];
}
var options = {
    scaleFontColor: "#f00",
    datasetStrokeWidth: 20
};

new Chart(ctx).Pie(data,options);
```

Comment: that works well and as you rightly said I'm only getting the last value in the loop, so you reckon I can get all the values of the loop? should not be more than 10...

Comment: Check it out again... we use an array instead and push the values to it everyloop cycle... I updated the code.